# Scons rebuilds everything under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: scons

I'm doing build management for a fairly large C++ project. Under Ubuntu with Linux 18.04, using Python 2.7, scons behaves as it should - that is,

```
make clean
scons <command line options>
scons <command line options>
```

the first scons will compile all the targets, but the second scons will not compile any targets, because the timestamp dependencies will show the targets to be up-to-date. But when I do the same thing, with the same code-base, no changes at all, under Ubuntu with Linux 20.04, using Python 3.8, scons behaves differently.

```
make clean
scons <command line options>
scons <command line options>
```

BOTH scons executions re-build everything. I've tried using command line option --debug=explain, on the second scons build, and it tells me that each target is being rebuilt because ALL of its dependent files have changed. But examining their timestamps shows that they are all old. I have been studying Scons source code, but I have no idea how to debug this, and determine why it is happening.

Comment: I should note that I am calling Decider() with a parameter of 'MD5-timestamp'. I am now testing with a parameter of 'timestamp-newer' to see what happens. I'll report here on what happens.

Comment: Tried it with 'timestamp-newer' and it didn't solve the problem. Second build still re-built everything.

Comment: add `--debug=explain` on the second scons build and see if that gives you any clue why it's rebuilding.  What does `make clean` do?

Comment: Yes, I used --debug=explain on the second scons build - that's described above. It said that every dependency file - the source file and all the header files - had been changed. But my examination of their timestamps showed them to be older than the targets. The effect of make clean is to delete all the object files, forcing them to be rebuilt in the next scons invocation.

Comment: Do you know that SCons has a clean command as well? `scons -c` ? Are the files on a local filesystem? or a NFS filesystem?(or other remote file system)

Comment: The files are definitely on a local filesystem. I have gone on to code my own custom selector, and verified that if the custom selector always returns False (do not rebuild), scons still rebuilds everything under 20.04.

Comment: Any chance you can create a small reproducer? This is very odd and not reported by any other SCons users..

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce it, partly because it is a complex setup, partly because the files are company-proprietary. But I can report the results of my latest instrumented tests:

Comment: In /SCons/Node/__init__.py, around line 1447, is method changed(...), which decides whether to rebuild the target. It can decide to rebuild for several reasons. First, the Decider function can say "The target either doesn't exist, or is older than one of the dependencies. Rebuild it." But even if that doesn't happen, there is code that first tests "if self.has_builder():", which is always true, then tests "if bi.bactsig != newsig:". This is evaluating True under Linux 20.04, but False under Linux 18.04. Now, what is bi.bactsig? What is newsig? I will investigate further and report here.

Comment: Yeah. That codes in WIDE usage. I very much doubt that's the error. bactsig = build action signiture.

Comment: Does your build command line have some component that changes on every build? like `-DTIMESTAMP=<current time()>` ?

Comment: OK, but if I comment out that code, then scons works just fine - makes the same build decisions under Linux 20.04 that it makes under Linux 18.04. As for -DTIMESTAMP=<current time()>, no, nothing like that.

Comment: There's got to be something changing on the command line for those build actions. That's what the bactsig is created from.  I'd say just look a the very first target which is getting improperly rebuilt.  Also.. it might be better to come to SCons' discord server to work through this..  https://discord.gg/pejaFYrD9n or the users mailing list..